# Separate database table for user?

Tags: mysql, database, optimization

Here is a question from a newbie. I need to store music data(URL, artist ...) for each user. Should I put all data in one single table with distinct keys for each user. Or maybe it is good idea to have separate tables for each user.
I am making an online player.
Thanks in advance

Comment: It is almost never a good idea to have a table for each of the different users unless you are limiting rights to view certain content.

Comment: Voting to close as "too broad". Read a book about database design...

Comment: The reason I am asking is this. If everyone's music data are in one table, the performance could go down because the table will be accessed thousand times a day and a each user will go through whole database. Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

A separate table for each user is not appropriate.

You need one table for the music data (URL, artist, ...).

If the only item you store about users is the name, you can put that into the music data table as well without violating database design principles too much.

As soon as you store additional information about users (e.g. password, e-mail address) you need a second table for the user data and connect the music data to the user data via a foreign key in the music data table (or, in case of a n:m relation, a third table).

If you are looking for further information about database design, keywords are *functional dependency* and *normalization*.

Answer (score 0):

You will create huge database if you are going to create seprate table for each user, make a table structure that will contain entries of all user in single table....

Answer (score 0):

Create a single table with different user privileges for ex create an
 group column table and provide different grouids to different users
 e.g. groupid =1 for admin ,2 for normal user etc.

Answer (score 0):

Enhanced relationship diagrams may help you in designing your database. It might be worth mapping out your proposed database using these diagrams before you implement them.
This is a good tool to make sure you have a correct database design for you and as previously said below deal with functional dependency and normalization.

This is a good website to help you if you haven't done this before: http://users.csc.calpoly.edu/~jdalbey/205/Lectures/HOWTO-ERD.html